# IOS Photon Cloud SDK getRoomList function doesn't work

Tags: ios, cloud, photon

I am developing cocos2d-x game which have online game mode.
Online game designed and implemented by Photon Cloud SDK(http://www.exitgames.com).
I implemented only ios version but it doesn't work.
The codes that I have implemented are blow.

void NetworkLogic::opJoinRandomRoom() 
{

```
ExitGames::Common::JVector<ExitGames::LoadBalancing::Room> roomList;
roomList = mLoadBalancingClient.getRoomList();

int count = roomList.getSize();
CCLog("Room Count = %d", count);
if(count == 0)
{

    this->opCreateRoom();

}else{

    mLoadBalancingClient.opJoinRandomRoom();

}
```

}

void NetworkLogic::update(float dt)
{

```
this->run();
```

}

void NetworkLogic::run(void)
{

```
if(mLastInput == INPUT_EXIT && mStateAccessor.getState() != STATE_DISCONNECTING && mStateAccessor.getState() != STATE_DISCONNECTED)
{
    disconnect();
    mStateAccessor.setState(STATE_DISCONNECTING);
}
else
{
    State state = mStateAccessor.getState();
    switch(state)
    {
    case STATE_INITIALIZED:
        connect();
        mStateAccessor.setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
        break;
    case STATE_CONNECTING:
        break; // wait for callback
    case STATE_CONNECTED:
        {
            ExitGames::Common::JVector<ExitGames::LoadBalancing::Room> roomList;
            roomList = mLoadBalancingClient.getRoomList();

            int count = roomList.getSize();
            ExitGames::Common::JString tmp;
            tmp = count;
            EGLOG(ExitGames::Common::DebugLevel::INFO, tmp);
            CCLog("Room count in Room = %d", count);
            switch(mLastInput)
            {

                case INPUT_CREATE_GAME: // create Game
                    opCreateRoom();
                    break;
                case INPUT_JOIN_RANDOM_GAME: // join Game
                    opJoinRandomRoom();
                    mStateAccessor.setState(STATE_JOINING);
                    break;
                default: // no or illegal input -> stay waiting for legal input
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
    case STATE_JOINING:
        break; // wait for callback
    case STATE_JOINED:
        switch(mLastInput)
        {
        case INPUT_LEAVE_GAME: // leave Game
            mLoadBalancingClient.opLeaveRoom();
            mStateAccessor.setState(STATE_LEAVING);
            break;
        default: // no or illegal input -> stay waiting for legal input
            break;
        }
        break;
    case STATE_LEAVING:
        break; // wait for callback
    case STATE_LEFT:
        mStateAccessor.setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
        break;
    case STATE_DISCONNECTING:
        break; // wait for callback
    default:
        break;
    }
}
mLastInput = INPUT_NON;
mLoadBalancingClient.service();
```

}
First I run one app then getRoomList function returns 0 values.
Also after first room created and run second app but it also returns getRoomList function 0.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just taken the code that you have provided in your question and copied it into the according place inside the demo of an otherwise unchanged version 3.2.2.0 build of the Photon C++ Client SDK (and removed the two CCLog() lines to make it compile without cocos2d-x) and it worked just fine for me:
The demo prints 0 for the size of the room list until I let one client create a room. Afterwards the other client prints 1.